# How to Filter on a ListView using a Custom CursorAdapter

Tags: android

I'm displaying contacts on a ListView using a Custom CursorAdapter as I retrieve these contacts from my database in a Cursor.
I would like to filter on this ListView with a SearchView, I know I have to use `.setFilterQueryProvider()` on my Adapter, but I have no idea how.

I tried to do this

```
...

adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        @Override
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence charSequence) {
            String[] args = new String[1];
            args[0]=charSequence.toString();
            return SugarRecord.getCursor(Contact.class, "FIRST_NAME like ?", args, null, null, null);
        }
    });

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            if(s != null && s.length() != 0)
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            if(s != null && s.length() != 0)
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

but it looks very messy and it doesn't work.

Here's my adapter

```
public class ContactAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

public ContactAdapter (Context context, Cursor cursor){
    super(context, cursor, 0);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.contact_item, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView textViewFirstNameRead = view.findViewById(R.id.TextViewFirstNameRead);
    TextView textViewLastNameRead = view.findViewById(R.id.TextViewLastNameRead);

    String firstName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("FIRST_NAME"));
    String lastName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("LAST_NAME"));

    textViewFirstNameRead.setText(firstName);
    textViewLastNameRead.setText(lastName);
}
```

}

Any idea how I should proceed ?